# Unable to deploy Rails App to DigitalOcean because of unsupported key type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I have configured the droplet in DO and nginx is up and running successfully. I followed the guide on DO on deploying to server via Capistrano. I can ssh into the server without entering my password. But on running `bundle exec cap production deploy:initial` I'm getting a very weird error:

`cap aborted!
NotImplementedError: unsupported key type`�pl+�lI���D��`���U����X��K\�L�[�\�
                                                                             �M�\�
                                                                                  �M�A?d��h"sU�Ǐ�2�?h��a    5G͕�E���%!Cg��j�|��tu�yL*�'/9�s۷'`

I'm using rsa SSH key and this has been working with many (>10) servers seamlessly. I tried to remove the `ssh_options` param from my `deploy/production.rb` file. This should ask for the server password before (I guess?). But I get the same error, leading me to suspect that something else is tripping me up.

Gem Versions:

`net-ssh (3.2.0)
capistrano (3.6.0)
sshkit (1.11.2)`

Comment: Could you try updating net-ssh?

Comment: And can you post the versions of capistrano, sshkit, and net-ssh?

Comment: updated the versions in question details.
3.2.0 is the latest stable version for net-ssh.

Comment: Could you run `ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'` and report back what it says?

Comment: @will_in_wi the output is: `OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016`

Comment: check for newlines in your ssh key (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057251/capistrano-unsupported-key-type)

Comment: @RaVeN there's no newline in my ssh key

Comment: Its because the string is not parsed correctly. It has something to do with utf-8 character set.

Comment: @user1735921 how can I check/change the char set?

Comment: that you will have to figure out yourself, i can just give you a hint

Comment: @tekina Just a leap in the dark here, but it might be the SSH server config. See the answer here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16784 on how to pass along your locale settings with the SSH session.

Comment: @wrdevos thanks for the suggestion. I'll check it once I get back to work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have stumbled across a bug in sshkit. Recent versions of sshkit have a custom SSH key-loading and caching mechanism aimed at improving connection performance.

However it seems that the custom implementation is not as bulletproof as the default net-ssh implementation that it replaces. Specifically, net-ssh will silently ignore keys that it doesn't support. The sshkit custom key-loader does not do this, so it blows up with the `unsupported key type` error you are seeing.

If my theory is correct, then you should be able to fix your issue by turning off sshkit's custom key-loader and forcing the original net-ssh implementation to be used. You can do this by adding the following to your `deploy.rb`:

```
set :ssh_options, known_hosts: Net::SSH::KnownHosts
```

Comment: Did not help, unfortunately. I'm able to deploy via my passphrase authentication, however.